# Error displaying Arabic and English text in the QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox and a QLineEdit when I type a text consisting of Arabic then English in order within the QLineEdit and after I enter that text to the QComboBox via the button, but the QComboBox reflects the text in English first then Arabic, and it doesn't display the required text. I think the problem is in the QComboBox

See the image below as a link for clarification

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(200, 150, 200, 30)
        self.combo_box.setStyleSheet("QComboBox { combobox-popup: 0; }")
        self.combo_box.setMaxVisibleItems(7)
        #self.combo_box.setEditable(True)

        self.text = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text.setGeometry(200,200,150,30)
        self.push = QPushButton(self)
        self.push.setText("ADD")
        self.push.setGeometry(200,250,150,30)
        self.push.clicked.connect(self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        self.combo_box.addItem(self.text.text())

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
App.setStyle("FUSION")
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a Qt5 bug (which I also reproduce in Qt6) where QComboBox does not use the direction in the painting. A possible solution is to apply the direction in the QApplication:

```py
App.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, thank you, I have another question similar to this one, please go to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935102/error-displaying-arabic-and-english-text-in-the-qtextdocument